# Node.js, net.socket, decoding Cyrillic characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is my code:

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        socket.destroy();
    });
}).listen(5000);
```

I'm using telnet 127.0.0.1 5000 to connect to the server.
I set socket encodig to UTF-8.
The script works fine until we send a string containing "some" cyrrillic characters.

For example:

```
data = абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя;
```

`console.log()` outputs `абвгдеёжзийклмнопрст�����ф�цчшщьыъэю�����`

What's wrong with the encoding? Why only several characters (х,у,я) turns into question marks?

I googled this problem for an hours. Didn't find anything decided to ask you.

Comment: You should use something like [`netcat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) instead of telnet (which isn't a transparent pass-through network utility and may mangle your data).

Comment: @robertklep you are the genius! Thank you for suggestion! Never thought that the problem is in the telnet. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was neither node.js nor net.js module problem.
As @robertklep mentioned it's better to use netcat instead of telnet.